# How to jump in codeblocks from log to source file

Tags: codeblocks

Is there a way like in Visual Studio to jump from a output log to a source file ?

In VS it is possible to write to debug log with a special syntax like :
**__FILE__**(**__LINE__**): some logging text in my C++ file.
and with a double click jump to that source file.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible in Code::Blocks.